# ffmpeg Attach file from stream

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, matroska

I have a flac source file with an embedded cover art, and what to convert it into an mka while retaining the cover art. The problem being that matroska requires cover arts to be attached.
I can extract the original cover using

`ffmpeg -i target.flac -vcodec copy cover.jpg`

and later add it to the mka using `-attach`. My question is, whether there is any way not to load the attached data from a file, but instead from the first command (as stream) and do this inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the matroska muxer only accepts streams classified as type attachment. Which is at present, only possible, using `-attach`. Only muxers, like MP4, can work with streams flagged with a disposition of attached pictures, and dispositions can be assigned inline.